# Can't promote WS2016 Core to additional DC - The folder C:\Windows\NTDS is not valid

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Core and I'm trying to promote it to an additional Domain Controller. I use this command:

```
 Install-ADDSDomainController -CreateDnsDelegation:$false -DatabasePath 'C:\Windows\NTDS' -DomainName 'testdomain.net' -InstallDNS:$false -LogPath 'C:\Windows\NTDS\' -NoGlobalCatalog:$true -SysVolPath 'C:\Windows\SYSVOL' -NoRebootOnCompletion:$false -Force:$true -Credential (Get-Credential TESTDOMAIN\Administrator)
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Install-ADDSDomainController : Verification of prerequisites
for Domain Controller promotion failed. The folder C:\Windows\NTDS\ is
not valid. Specify a valid path, including drive letter. For
example: C:\NTDS.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-ADDSDomainController -CreateDnsDelegation:$false
-DatabasePat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-ADDSD
   omainController], TestFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Test.VerifyDcPromoCore.DCPromo.G
   eneral.37,Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Deployment.PowerShel
   l.Commands.InstallADDSDomainControllerCommand
```

I also tried creating the folder but I still get that error. I even used C:\NTDS (As the error suggested for me to do) but I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue.  It's the trailing backslash after the `-LogPath 'C:\Windows\NTDS\'`.  You just want `-LogPath 'C:\Windows\NTDS'`.